# .length in array does not make sense to me

Tags: arrays

If there is a code that goes `myVar = ['ada']` then you go `myVar.length - 1` this should equal the last letter in the string.

This is a bit confusing to me. Should it not be the 2nd letter since `myVar.length` would be 2(as in 0-1-2) and if subtracted by 1 it should end up as 1 meaning the code should link to the letter D

Comment: `myVar` is an array. So `myVar.length-1` will give you the last (and only) element in your array, which is the string `'ada'`. If `myVar` was the string `'ada'`, then `myVar.length` would be 3 (not 2), and so 3-1 gives 2, which would be the last character in your string `'ada'`

Answer (score 1):

Length usually returns number of elements in array. And in your case it would be 3. And since arrays are usually 0-based (means first index is 0 not 1) the index if last element is length - 1.
You are mixing length and index of an element because in your suggestion array with only one element will have length equal to 0 which is wrong since array has 1 element and array with length 0 is an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about index?

It's basically like if I tell you to write a list of numbers on paper, and I tell you to say out loud in reverse order. So it's index will start from 1 but in reverse(-). First from below/last, second from below/last and so on.

[Arrays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdrRM.png)

Source : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-arrays/